# PyQt5 выполнить действие по нажатию на кнопку или Enter в поле ввода

Tags: python, pyqt5

Здравствуйте, имею простенькую программу написанную на Python на модуле PyQt5(Как вы могли понять по заголовку), и так у меня есть задача, что-бы после ввода в поле при нажатии кнопки или enter выполнялось бы указанное действие, надеюсь на помощь!

Comment: Кнопки или ENTER

Comment: связанный вопрос [Detecting enter on a QLineEdit or QPushButton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15561608/4279)

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы по нажатию <kbd>Enter</kbd> в текстовом поле или на кнопке выполнялось действие, можно соединить соответствующие сигналы (`returnPressed`) со слотами (`click`):

```
button.clicked.connect(sync_lcd)  # update LCD on click
button.setAutoDefault(True)  # click on <Enter>
textfield.returnPressed.connect(button.click)  # click on <Enter>
```

Первая строчка говорит: по щелчку мыши по кнопке (`button`) вызывать функцию `sync_lcd`. Следующие две строчки делают равнозначным щелчку мыши нажатие <kbd>Enter</kbd> на кнопке или в текстовом поле. Полный пример:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Perform action on <Enter> or click."""
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLCDNumber, QLineEdit, QPushButton,
                             QGridLayout, QWidget)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle('<Enter> or click')
lcd = QLCDNumber(4)
button = QPushButton('Enter')
textfield = QLineEdit('123')
textfield.setFocus()

grid = QGridLayout()
grid.addWidget(lcd, 1, 1, 1, 2)  # first row, span two columns
grid.addWidget(textfield, 2, 1)  # 2nd row, 1st column
grid.addWidget(button, 2, 2)     # 2nd row, 2nd column
window.setLayout(grid)


def sync_lcd():
    lcd.display(textfield.text())


button.clicked.connect(sync_lcd)  # update LCD on click
button.setAutoDefault(True)  # click on <Enter>
textfield.returnPressed.connect(button.click)  # click on <Enter>
sync_lcd()

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Можно привязать событие к любому изменению текста (тогда кнопка излишня будет):

```
textfield.textChanged.connect(sync_lcd)  # perform action on any text change
```