# PyQt5 вывести информацию из поля ввода нажатием кнопки Enter

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Есть программа, написанная на модуле `PyQt5`. Нужно, чтобы после ввода в поле, действие выполнялось нажатием на кнопку `Enter`.

Найденную в гугле инфу по теме добавила в код, но не работает. Спасибо заранее за помощь начинающим.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(240, 180)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName('<Enter> or click')
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 20, 230, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 60, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 120, 181, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 240, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.myFunction)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Enter')



    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Окно"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Кнопка"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Длина Вашего текста"))

    def myFunction(self):
        self.label.setText("Длина Вашего текста %d" % len(self.lineEdit.text()))

    def sync_lcd(self, MainWindow):
        lcd.display(self.lineEdit())
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(sync_lcd)
        self.pushButton.setAutoDefault(True)
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.pushButton.click)
        sync_lcd()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [PyQt5 выполнить действие по нажатию на кнопку или Enter в поле ввода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/793143/pyqt5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-enter-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)

Comment: Странная функция `sync_lcd` :) Ее и нужно вызывать?

Comment: кроме названия что-то в ней смущает? myFunction2 Вас бы больше устроило? ее, если она может связать введенную в поле информацию с клавишей Enter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не надо искать в гугле, полистайте поста данного сайта и вы много найдете интересного.

Вы не внимательно прочитали, что вам написал @gil9red 
и дело тут не названии, а в том, что ее (т.е. этод метод `sync_lcd`) -`нужно вызывать`.

Предположительно потому, что в этом методе прописана (не правильно) строка:

```
lcd.display(self.lineEdit())
```

правильно будет так:

```
self.lcd.display(self.lineEdit.text())
```

но объект `self.lcd` должен быть создан заранее:

```
self.lcd = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
```

Также надо отметить, что в `QLCDNumber` могут быть показаны:

- цифры: 0/O, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5/S, 6, 7, 8, 9/g;
- минус, десятичная точка, двоеточие, знак степени (который указан в строке одинарной кавычкой), пробел,
- некоторые буквы A, B, C, D, E, F, h, H, L, o, P, r, u, U, Y;

QLCDNumber заменяет недопустимые символы - на пробел.

Для того чтобы вызвать на исполнение метод `sync_lcd` 
вы должны соединить событие `self.lineEdit` сигналом `returnPressed` со слотом `sync_lcd`

```
self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.sync_lcd)
```

**Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный `Qt Designer`**. Создайте другой класс, 
который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Пример, который вы нашли должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(240, 240)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName('<Enter> or click')
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 20, 230, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 60, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 160, 181, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 240, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.myFunction)
#        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Enter')

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Окно"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Кнопка"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Длина Вашего текста"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.myFunction)

        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.sync_lcd)                     # sync_lcd !!!

        self.lcd = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcd.setDigitCount(10)
        self.lcd.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 90, 230, 50))

    def myFunction(self):
        self.label.setText("Длина Вашего текста %d" % len(self.lineEdit.text()))

    def sync_lcd(self):
        self.lcd.display(self.lineEdit.text())
#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(sync_lcd)
#        self.pushButton.setAutoDefault(True)
#        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.pushButton.click)
#        sync_lcd()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]